# What is the correct place to inject/load a service that contains self-registering components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am working on an AngularJS application that has some self-registering components. Concretely, there are some services that do not directly offer any public interface themselves; they merely register some internal objects in some directory provided by another service.

You can imagine the body of such a service's factory as follows:

```
var internalThing = {
    // members ...
};
thingRegistryService.registerThing(internalThing);

return {};
```

Thus, I only need to ensure that the service gets loaded at some point.

The dilemma I'm facing is as follows: As the service provides no public functions and just needs to "be there", there is no reason to inject it anywhere. As it does not get injected, it never gets instantiated. As it never gets instantiated, the components within the service never register themselves, though.

I can inject the service the usual where in some service or controller that I know will get loaded - but then, I am basically leaving an unused argument in the code (which, if it is the last argument in the list, will even get outlined as an error based on the project's JSHint settings).

Alternatively, I can do the self-registration in a method in the service and call that wherever I inject the service. This would make the service injection "useful", but in turn I'd have to deal with multiple calls myself instead of relying on the built-in singleton mechanism of AngularJS's services.

Or ... should I go yet another route, by providing a method like `registerThing` somewhere that takes the service name as a string, and that will internally just invoke `$injector.get`? Of course, that evokes the question again where the correct place to put that kind of call would be.

---

A little background: This is part of a large project developed in a large team. Build and/or deployment magic somehow handles that any JavaScript code file committed to our VCS by any developer will be available to AngularJS's dependency injection. Thus, any JavaScript that needs to be added has to be provided as some kind of an AngularJS service, controller, etc.

---

**What is the proper way to load such a self-registering service?**

Answer (score 0):

Right place to init your module is `angular.module('yourModule').run` block.

In case of "self-registering" I think it is better to have some implicit method for this:

```
angular.module('yourModule').run(['service'], function (service) {
  service.init();
})
```

Comment: This sounds like a good answer. I just have one question: "I think it is better to have some implicit method for this" - why? Sure, it suppresses the JSHint message, but other than that, it seems redundant (the self-registering service is already "required" by the mere fact that it gets injected), maybe even slightly harmful (if the service is required by various modules, and should register when it is first loaded, by whichever module that is, an explicit `init()` call requires me to add custom logic to ensure initialization happens only once, which would automatically be the case for ...

Comment: ... injected lazily instantiated singleton services).

Answer (score 0):

If your build system magically provides all JS code, is an import needed?

A self-registering architecture as your build system suggests should not require imports. The import JSHint errors are the cost of this magic.

I've used a similar behavior with namespace-like design. It can be used for self-registering techniques, although imports get tricky and does not work well with ES6 modules.

This is close to my point: http://blog.assaf.co/automating-component-registration-in-angularjs/

Comment: "If your build system magically provides all JS code, is an import needed?" - if by "import" you mean "injection", then ... yes, I think so. The build system just finds and adds all the JavaScripts files. It has no idea about the content of these files, and dependencies between the services in these files. Consequently, the build system has no way of instantiating the services in the correct order. The article you linked to summarizes "Describe a factory for every component. (...) Go over every item in a group and register it." - which is exactly what one does when declaring AngularJS ...

Comment: ... services the way it is shown in the first code snippets in that article. It is not clear to me how "go over every item in a group and register it" solves the issue that the order of registering these items is important.

Comment: Oh, I see that the problem is the registration order rather than a simple hint or import.

Comment: Indeed. The problem is not that I cannot register my service with Angular's dependency injector and then inject it where I need it. That could work perfectly fine. The problem is that I do not "need" that service with the self-registering components anywhere (as in, I never want to call anything directly on that service), hence I never request its injection, hence it never gets instantiated (and the components therein never register themselves). The sanest point of enforcing that the self-registration has happened would be whenever the self-registering components are about to be retrieved ...

Comment: ... but at the same time, that would defeat the purpose of having self-registering (decoupled!) components as the retrieving service would then have to know all the services with such self-registering components (= directly coupled!).